Processing snowpark tables inside a UDTF - Session not found
I have created a small udtf to highlight my current challenge. I need to process different tables depending on some parameters (the udtf can take any table at any point in time).
A snowpark session is already available.
I am passing the table as string to my function and in process I am trying to get the active session so I can reference my table as dataframe, do some processing and return the processed table.
This udtf will eventually run inside a dbt python model (haven't reached that part yet).
I have tried so far:

add __init__

def __init__(self):
        self.session = get_active_session()  # Store the passed session object

and no luck so far.
Here is my example
from snowflake.snowpark.types import StructField, StructType, StringType, IntegerType, FloatType
from snowflake.snowpark.context import get_active_session
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import udtf, table_function,lit
import simplejson as json
udtf_schema = StructType([StructField("json_output", StringType())])

@udtf(output_schema=udtf_schema,input_types=[StringType()],packages=["simplejson", "snowflake-snowpark-python"],is_permanent=False,replace=True)
class example_udtf:
  def process(self, sp_table):
      session = get_active_session()
      df = session.table(sp_table)
      df_with_json = df.select(
                    F.to_json(
                        F.struct(
                            *[F.col(col) for col in df.columns]  # Dynamically include all columns in the DataFrame
                        )
                    ).alias("json_output")
        )
      for part in df_with_json.to_local_iterator():
          result = { "value":part}
          yield (json.dumps(result),)
                
tbl = session.table_function(example_udtf.name,lit("db.schema.my_existing_sf_table")).collect()

Produces the following error
nowflake.snowpark.exceptions.SnowparkSessionException: (1403): No default Session is found. Please create a session before you call function 'udf' or use decorator '@udf'.
 in function SNOWPARK_TEMP_TABLE_FUNCTION_A8U80M1DGL with handler compute

Maybe this is currently not possible?
I don't want to create a SP as dbt already wrap the dbt model in a SP plus I'd lose lineage.
TIA

If you are creating the utdf out of the snowflake python worksheet then first you need to establish the session by passing the snowflake credentials.
from snowflake.snowpark import Session
# Define connection parameters
connection_parameters = {
    "account": "account",
    "user": "user",
    "password": "password",
    "role": "role",
    "warehouse": "warehouse",
    "database": "SF_RAG_APP",
    "schema": "RAG_APP_SCHEMA"
}

def get_snowpark_session():
    """ Get or create a Snowpark session """
   return Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()

# Use this function to get a single session instead of creating new ones
session = get_snowpark_session()


The session is already available I thought that was clear. It is passing the session to the udtf where the challenge is
